# Dailymotion iframe on HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm working on a `https` website and I'm trying to load in an iframe, a `http` dailymotion video.

I have the standard error :

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://mywebsite' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure
>   resource 'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/myvideo'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there a good solution for this ?I know Youtube has something for this, but Dailymotion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your requested resource to `https://www.dailymotion.com` That should fix the problem.

Read the error, it says it is an insecure resource being served using `http` and says you need `https`